# print the ratio of Fibonacci numbers until a specific condition

Tags: python

I will print to screen first 70 Fibonacci numbers. And then in the same script I also want to print `F(i+1)/F(i)` ratio until a defined `F(i+1)-F(i)<=536` condition is met.

My script prints first 70 Fibonacci numbers but it doesn't print the ratio `F(i+1)/F(i)`.

It gives the following error:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "fib.py", line 13, in 
>       while b-a > 536:
>
> NameError: name 'b' is not defined

In my code a and b represent F(i) and F(i+1), respectively. How can I fix my code?

```
#!/usr/bin/python

def F(n):
    a, b = 0, 1
    for i in range(0, n):
        a, b = b, a+b
    return a

for c in range(0, 70):
    print(F(c))

while b-a > 536:              
   print 'Ratio:', b/a
```

Comment: You speal about ratio but you do you compare with a minus in your while.

Comment: @maggick Note:1-)The code will print first 70 Fibonacci number. 2-)The code will print all `F(i+1)/F(i)` ratios (not just one ratio) until a defined `F(i+1)-F(i)<=536` condition is met.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
a,b = 0,1
l = []
def F(n):
    global a
    global b
    a,b = 0,1
    for i in range(0, n):
        a, b = b, a+b
    return a

for c in range(0, 70):
    num = F(c)
    print(num)
    l.append(num)

for i in range(0, len(l)-2):
    if l[i+1]-l[i] <= 536:
        #print b
        #print a
        print 'Ratio:', float(b)/a
```

Comment: `@shruti1810` your code works but it just prints one ratio value. Whereas it should print those ratios until this `b-a > 536`condition.

Comment: I din't know that. Put the if condition inside `for` loop then.

Comment: Firstly the code should write first 70 Fibonacci numbers (your code does it).  After the code prints first 70 Fibonacci numbers (it will happen in the first for-loop), and then it should start to print `float(b)/a` ratios until this `b-a > 536` condition (this part should be in the second for-loop and for second for-loop the `range (0, 70)` shouldn't specify. Because it is depend on our condition. Maybe for our condition we need `85` Fibonacci numbers. We dont know how many Fibonacci numbers are enough for that condition). I think you can edit your code?

Comment: And do you mean you want to print all those ratios where b-a <=536 or b-a >536?

Comment: Yes. I hope you can do it. Condition:b-a <=536

Comment: b-a <=536 or b-a >536?

Comment: The condition is b-a <=536.

Comment: Edited the answer. Let me know if this is what was expected?

Answer (score 0):

`b` is not definied in your while (as `a`).
In fact `a` and `b` are only define in the `F(n)` function and they are local variables.

You should read some documentation about Programming and python first. But the following code should works:

(I suppose that you want `while a/b <= 536` as this is not clear in your question)

```
def F(n):
    a, b = 0, 1
    for i in range(0, n):
        a, b = b, a+b
    return a, b

for c in range(0, 70):
    a,b = F(c)
    print(a)

while a/b <= 536:              
   print('Ratio:{}/{}'.format(b,a))
   a, b = F(a)
```

An other solution is to totaly rewrite your code:

```
def F(a, b):
    c = a + b
    return c,a

a, b = 0, 1
for c in range (0,70):
    a, b = F(a,b)
    print (a)

while a/b <=536:
    print(a/b)
    a,b = F(a, b)
```

Comment: `@maggick` your code gives this error:`Traceback (most recent call last):File "fib.py", line 15, in <module>a, b = F(a) File "fib.py", line 5, in F for i in range(0, n):MemoryError`. And it should print those ratios until this `b-a > 536` condition.

Comment: @erhan The error seems to be due to a lack of memory (RAM) in your computer. I do not have this issue (with python3). Moreover `b-a> 536` is never valid after the 70th iteration of fibonnacci !

Answer (score 0):

```
def F(n):
    a, b = 0, 1
    for i in range(0, n):
        a, b = b, a+b
    return a
factorials = []
for c in range(0, 70):
    factorials.append((F(c)))

for i in xrange(1,len(factorials)-1):
    if factorials[i+1] - (factorials[i]) > 536:
        print "ratio :"+str(factorials[i+1]/float(factorials[i]))
```

The output mainly consists of integers starting with `1.61803`, Is that what you were trying to achieve ?

Answer (score 0):

```
def FR(n):
    a, b = 0, 1
    for i in range(0, n):
       a, b = b, a+b
    return a , b/float(a) if b-a > 536 else None


for c in range(0, 70):
    fb , ra = FR(c)
    print fb if ra is None else fb,' Ratio:', ra
```